# Deploy ASP MVC 3 application under IIS 7 Default Web Site: File not found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, url-rewriting, global-asax

My Default Web Site on IIS is pointing at

> "C:/intepub/wwwroot"

. In this directory, I have place a subdirectory called "mvc" that contains the files needed to run the MVC 3 web app. Therefore the physical path of my web app and its files is

> "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/mvc"

It allows me to access the Login page with no problem, however any other route defined in the Global.asax file throws a **404 error**. I have tried this test:

The route **http://myDomain/Module/CO1040 throws and error**, **but** when a hardcoded the url and insert "mvc" on it, i.e. **http://myDomain/mvc/Module/CO1040**, it **works perfectly.**

**Does this means that I have to rewrite the routes in Global.asax to insert that "mvc"?**
I've gone through the documentation for deploying MVC web apps on IIS 7 and everything points at I shouldn't have any url rewriting to do (I've also looked into the different methods to do this, driving me a bit more crazy), since IIS 7 makes this deployment easier than previous versions of IIS.

How can I solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you point your IIS virtual directory at C:/inetpub/wwwroot/mvc?

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the answer for this ? I have the same issue

UPDATE

I Found my issue. You have do enable the 32 bit application to True from the APP Pool